# Age field converted from varchar to integer, but now I want to group on age in SQL View

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-view

I inherited a database that the age field is a `varchar`. So in a SQL view, I'm converting it to integer as such `CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) AS IND_AGE`.

However I now want to group those ages.   I would like to add a column to say what bucket they fall into so I can graph the statistics.  Here is the whole SQL view.  Could someone help me?  I greatly appreciate it.  The age range can be as simple as <18, 18-25, >=26

```
SELECT
    Name.ID,
    Name.STATUS,
    Name.MEMBER_TYPE,
    Name.CATEGORY,
    CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) AS IND_AGE,
    IND_DEMO.AGE
FROM Name
INNER JOIN IND_DEMO
    ON Name.ID = IND_DEMO.ID
WHERE (Name.STATUS = 'A')
AND (Name.MEMBER_TYPE LIKE 'ind%')
AND (NOT (IND_DEMO.AGE LIKE '%.%'))
AND (IND_DEMO.AGE <> '')
```

Comment: What do you mean "group" the ages? Do you want to add a column `AgeBucket` with values '<18', '18-25', '>=26'? Or do you want to aggregate by the buckets (e.g. get a `COUNT`, `SUM`, or `AVG` of some other measure?

Comment: Yes, I forgot to mention that, thank you.  I would like to add a column to say what bucket they fall into so I can graph the statistics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this with case

```
SELECT
    Name.ID,
    Name.STATUS,
    Name.MEMBER_TYPE,
    Name.CATEGORY,
    CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) AS IND_AGE,
    CASE WHEN CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) < 18 THEN '<18' 
         WHEN CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) >= 18 and CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE)< 26 THEN '18-25'
         ELSE '>=26' END AS AgeRange,
    IND_DEMO.AGE
FROM Name
INNER JOIN IND_DEMO
    ON Name.ID = IND_DEMO.ID
WHERE (Name.STATUS = 'A')
AND (Name.MEMBER_TYPE LIKE 'ind%')
AND (NOT (IND_DEMO.AGE LIKE '%.%'))
AND (IND_DEMO.AGE <> '')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT Name.ID, Name.STATUS, Name.MEMBER_TYPE, Name.CATEGORY, CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) AS IND_AGE, IND_DEMO.AGE
FROM Name 
INNER JOIN IND_DEMO 
    ON Name.ID = IND_DEMO.ID
WHERE
    (Name.STATUS = 'A') 
    AND (Name.MEMBER_TYPE LIKE 'ind%') 
    AND (NOT (IND_DEMO.AGE LIKE '%.%')) AND (IND_DEMO.AGE <> '')
Group By Name.ID, Name.STATUS, Name.MEMBER_TYPE, Name.CATEGORY, CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE), IND_DEMO.AGE
Having CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) < 18 
    AND CONVERT(int, IND_DEMO.AGE) >=26
```

Comment: I tried running this query, but I receive an error on line 9 in the grouping for the 'AS' part.  Thank you for trying